# Daylight Savings How?

Tags: datetime, solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

How are you handling Daylight Savings Time with Solspace Calendar event elements?

In our part of the world (America/Detroit), we seasonally offset our clocks by one hour, twice a year.

Let's say we have three events with identical starting times. Two of those events take place after November 3 -- when the time changes.

In the database, these three start dates appear like so:

```
2022-10-18 18:30:00
2022-11-15 18:30:00
2022-12-06 18:30:00
```

We parse those out on the front end and the two dates after November 3 display a start time that is offset by one hour.

```
{% set startDate = event.startDate %}
{{ startDate|date('F jS', timezone='America/Detroit') }}
```

How is this happening? How might we compensate?

````
Craft CMS 3.7.56
Solspace Calendar Pro 3.3.16
PHP 7.4.30
MySQL 5.5.5 - 10.83-MariaDB```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the three dates should all appear as the same time on the frontend, as if there was no regional time change?

You can do this by using Calendars `.format()` method on startDate, like `event.startDate.format('F jS')` or continue using the `|date` filter with the `event.startDateLocalized` property like `event.startDateLocalized|date('F jS g:ia', timezone='America/Detroit')`

Comment: +1 for the reference to `startDateLocalized`, which isn't documented on the main [Event object reference](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/calendar/v4/templates/objects/event/), but nicely resolves [Solspace Calendar ignoring Craft CMS's Time Zone configuration](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/calendar/v4/setup/faq/#how-does-calendar-handle-timezones). That mitigates a lot of issues and helps avoid confusion when using Craft's [`|date`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/filters.html#date) or [`|datetime`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/filters.html#datetime) filters.